# Error, list object not callable

Tags: python, python-3.5, pythonanywhere

Here is my code:

```
firstname = ["Mark", "Rohan", "Matt" , "Anthony" , "Teddy" , "Kyle" , "Bob"]
lastname = ["Wightman", "Red", "Silver" , "Blue" , "Green" , "Orange" , "Purple"]
age = ["15",'5', '16', '21years', '17.6', '19', '-18', '917']

input_firstname = input('What is first name?: ')
input_lastname = input('What about your last name?: ')
input_age = input('What is your age?: ')

firstname.append(input_firstname)
lastname.append(input_lastname)
age.append(input_age)

index = 0
valid = True
for original in age:
    if len(original) < 2:
        valid = False
    elif original.isdigit() == False:
        valid = False
    elif (len(original) > 2) and original[2].isdigit():
        valid = False
    elif len(original) > 2 and original[2] == ".":
        neworiginal = original[0:2]
        original = neworiginal
    elif valid == True:
        print ("%s, %s, %s") %(firstname(original), lastname(original), age(original))
    index = index +1
```

This program should be printing the first name column, then the last name column, then the age column such as:
Mark, Wightman, 15
Rohan, Red, 5

And so on. However, when the code runs, there is an error saying that on the line "print ("%s, %s, %s") %(firstname(original), lastname(original), age(original)" the "list" object is not callable. The goal of this project is to use lists, for loops, and conditionals to clean the age data and print it out into 3 columns.

Comment: What are you expecting `firstname(original)` to do? Index into your list? If so index notation has the syntax `firstname[index]` where `index` is an integer.

Comment: Thank you, that changed a little, there is still an error. I am expecting it to index my list. The error it throws now is "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets instead of round when you want to get list element

I mean firstname[original] instead of firstname(original)

Comment: This gives the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Convert it to integer int(original)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers stated, you need to use brackets `[]` but you also need to convert `original` to `integer` so `firstname[int(original)]` and so on:

```
print ("%s, %s, %s") % (firstname[int(original)], lastname[int(original)], age[int(original)])
```

edit:

```
for i in range(len(firstname)):
    print ("%s, %s, %s") % (firstname[i], lastname[i], age[i])
```

Comment: This is because you are trying to access list `firstname` with index of `15` for example which doesn't exist. What are you trying to achieve by firstname[original] anyways?

Comment: I am trying to make all of the firstnames print out in a column.

Comment: Then why are you validating the ages in age list? you can loop through the length of any of the lists and print the items instead?

Comment: I'll try that next class, thank you a lot for your help.